# How to search from a value using VLookUp Excel function from lookup_value starting at end?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

[image: I have below Data]

I used below Vlookup formula to pick my desired data

```
=VLOOKUP(100,PersonDetails,2,FALSE)
```

Ideally i need the formula to fetch **Adress1 value (abc)** for the **key 100(lookup_value)** from the **named range(PersonDetails)** but the formula doesn't seems to get correct data (**#N/A** is displayed as result). Any workaround for this?

Note : PersonDetails is a named range and not a table.

Comment: This isn't VBA. Also, VLookup's work left to right, and only on one column. So your VLookup is looking for "100" in Column "Name" and returning the value from column "Address". however, i highly doubt there will ever be a "100" in the name column. If re-arranging your columns is acceptable, then put the "Key" column at the start and that will work.

Comment: Re-Arranging would work ,i know that.but i need to look up from right to left only.Only that would solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately VLOOKUP assumes the lookup column is the *first* column of the range, so unless you are able to change the order of the columns you can't do what you want.

The alternative (I wouldn't call it a workaround, it's generally argued that it is better) is to use MATCH and INDEX

The formula would look like this:-

```
=INDEX(PersonDetails,MATCH(100,INDEX(PersonDetails,,5),0),2)
```

In reverse order:-

The second INDEX specifies the fifth column of the range (Key).

The MATCH looks up the value 100 in the Key column and finds it in the first row of data.

The first INDEX returns the value in the first row and second column of the range (or the second row if the range includes the headers) (abc).

Comment: @ Tom Sharpe ,  Brilliant !! That worked.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column at the start with the key again, then just hide it, and keep your formula and table layout. But the previous answer is far better. E.g B5 formula =G5, then include column B in your range.

Comment: Ideally , I dont want to change the structure of Excel sheet .which means i don't need to add or remove any column.Thanks for your time though !